# How to get the value in field by new line and update into the column in table with same id in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to ask how to get the value of the column and update into another column with same id.. this data came from email piping and i want to separate the value of the body and update into the expense , net and gross field..

i hope you can help me guys.. thank you

```
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
| id   | subject | body               | expense |   net    | gross | email    |
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1   | Sales   | Expense = 2000     |    0    |    0     |   0   | ex@ex.com|
|      |         | netIncome = 5000   |         |          |       |          | 
|      |         | Gross    = 10000   |         |          |       |          |
+------+---------+--------------------+---------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: is this the data inside an RDBMS table?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have one `\n` for the line break and having the same pattern for the `body`, lets say we have the following

```
mysql> select * from test \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  id: 1
body: Expense = 2000
netIncome = 5000
Gross    = 10000
```

Now to get each amount we can use `substring_index` something as

```
mysql> select 
substring_index(substring_index(body,'=',-3),'\n',1) as expense, 
substring_index(substring_index(body,'=',-2),'\n',1) as netincome, 
substring_index(body,'=',-1) as gross from test;
+---------+-----------+--------+
| expense | netincome | gross  |
+---------+-----------+--------+
|  2000   |  5000     |  10000 |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

So for the update it could be as

```
update your_table
set 
expense = substring_index(substring_index(body,'=',-3),'\n',1),
net = substring_index(substring_index(body,'=',-2),'\n',1),
gross = substring_index(body,'=',-1) ;
```